# Apply for new ICT visa and cancel Tier 2 General visa

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, uk-visa

I have already got **UK Tier 2 General visa** am currently based in India. However on handing over my notice my company (in India) has agreed to send me via **UK ICT Long term visa**.

Please let me know the following:

1. If I do not proceed with Tier 2 General visa is there any restriction for my to apply a fresh ICT visa?
2. What is the procedure to cancel my Tier 2 General visa?
3. Am I entitled to get any refund like NHS surcharge?

I really need your guidance as I cannot find any specific point in Tier 2 Point based Guideline (PDF)